# How to configure Apache on Ubuntu

Tags: server, apache2

I have a server with Ubuntu 18.04.4 and I have installed Apache 2.4.29, but when I type the url of the server on a web browser, I just get a blank page. No error or anything.

This is my current ufw status:

```
(TCDigitalVenv) linuxmidtc@servermidtc:/var/log/apache2$ sudo ufw status numbered
[sudo] password for linuxmidtc: 
Status: active

     To                         Action      From
     --                         ------      ----
[ 1] Apache Full                ALLOW IN    Anywhere                  
[ 2] 22/tcp                     ALLOW IN    Anywhere                  
[ 3] 80                         ALLOW IN    Anywhere                  
[ 4] 80/tcp                     ALLOW IN    Anywhere                  
[ 5] Apache                     ALLOW IN    Anywhere                  
[ 6] Apache Full (v6)           ALLOW IN    Anywhere (v6)             
[ 7] 22/tcp (v6)                ALLOW IN    Anywhere (v6)             
[ 8] 80 (v6)                    ALLOW IN    Anywhere (v6)             
[ 9] 80/tcp (v6)                ALLOW IN    Anywhere (v6)             
[10] Apache (v6)                ALLOW IN    Anywhere (v6)
```

I have being following [this guide](https://phoenixnap.com/kb/how-to-install-apache-web-server-on-ubuntu-18-04), but I am pretty new to Apache, so I don't know what I have done wrongly.

**EDIT**
These are the commands I used to install Apache:

```
sudo apt upgrade
sudo apt install apache2 apache2-dev ufw
sudo ufw allow 'Apache Full'
```

I don't have the result messages, but I didn't get any error, but one warning:
`AH00558: apache2: Could not reliably determine the server's fully qualified domain name, using 127.0.1.1. Set the 'ServerName' directive`

Comment: You are getting a blank page, right? Not an error from the browser saying it can't connect?

Comment: @muru That's right

Comment: So your apache seems to be running fine, it's just that the default page isn't being shown. Please show the actual commands you ran while installing and the output you got.

Comment: @muru I edited the question with the information you request.